# Identifying submodule hash from top module

Tags: git

Is there a way to see what revision of a submodule is committed in a particular revision of the master module?  I know I could do this by checking out the particular version, pulling the submodule and checking the status of the submodule, but it seems a bit heavy to check out entire repos just to check the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git ls-tree`:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD submodule
160000 commit f7d1c4fa156f27cf52776d3238f6aca7f767d189  submodule
```